# Problem with Replace - it dosn't work for letter Ê

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have quite a strange problem. I have a column with surnames with national characters
I would like to replace national characters, so I made something like that

```
select replace(surname,'Ê','E')
```

for surname ABCDÊ as result still is ABCDÊ
but when I make a test and replace the value that I copied

```
select replace('ABCDÊ','Ê','E')
```

It works correctly and as result I get ABCDE

Comment: Your second example probably doesn't do what you think it's doing - depending on your database's default collation it could be replacing the `?` in `ABCD?` with `E`. When dealing with `nchar` and `nvarchar` values get in the habit of using National character literals so as to avoid the loss of Unicode characters that don't exist in your database's default collation. e.g.: compare the outputs from `select N'Ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ', 'Ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ'`

Answer (score 2):

Feel like something is missing here. Is it possible your column is using a case sensitive collation? If so, either will have to override it, or just replace each letter case individually (probably the better method to preserve original letter case).

### Adjusting for Case-Sensitive Collation

```
/*Collation abbreviation "CS" = Case-sensitive*/
DECLARE @table AS TABLE (surname VARCHAR(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES ('abcdê'),('ABCDÊ')

SELECT  surname
        ,YourOriginalCode = REPLACE(surname, 'Ê', 'E')          
        ,ForceCaseInsensitiveCollation = REPLACE(surname COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS , 'Ê', 'E') 
        ,ReplaceForEachLetterCase = REPLACE(REPLACE(surname,'Ê','E'),'ê','e') 
        ,SQLServer2017Version = TRANSLATE(surname,'êÊ','eE')
FROM  @table
```

### Results

| surname | YourOriginalCode | ForceCaseInsensitiveCollation | ReplaceForEachLetterCase | SQLServer2017Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcdê | abcdê | abcdE | abcde | abcde |
| ABCDÊ | ABCDE | ABCDE | ABCDE | ABCDE |

Answer (score 0):

This sort of issue usually comes down to how SQL stores unicode characters.

Try running the following to see what sort of output you get.  On my server both work fine, but it may well help you identify your issue.

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE ( surname VARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL )

INSERT INTO @table ( surname )
VALUES ( 'ABCDÊ' )
,      ( N'ABCDÊ' )

SELECT  surname
,       REPLACE(surname, 'Ê', 'E')
  FROM  @table
```